# Control shape proportions when Edit Point in PowerPoint 2010?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, vector-graphics, shapes

Is there a way to control the proportional point position while Edit Points for shapes in PowerPoint 2010? In other words, to get a straight line after repositioning a point (Like a 'Shift' button works in vector editing software)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a much-requested feature, but no. Not even in the latest version of PowerPoint.